# How to remove repeating values based on two different columns?

Tags: sas

Blockquote

For Ex. if I have the value "a" in COLUMN A the same value shouldn't appear in COLUMN A and COLUMN B. Now with "a", the value  "c" will also get selected for that observation. Now we need to make sure that "c" shouldn't appear anywhere in the table. Below is a sample Data set.

```
Col A   Col B
a   c
a   b
a   a
b   d
b   b
b   a
c   c
c   d
c   a
d   g
e   f
```

In the above case the result set should only contain

```
Col A   Col B
a   c
b   d
e   f
```

If I try with NODUPKEY with By Column A the result is mentioned below. But the values are repeating.

```
Col A   Col B
a   c
b   d
c   c
d   g
e   f
```

Please let me know.

Comment: Is (a b) (c d) (e f) a valid result set as well for the inputs you've given? If not, why not?

Comment: It can be a valid result set since no values are repeating. How to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing this, using a hash object to keep track of which values have been seen so far in either column while working through the dataset:

```
data have;
input (A B) ($);
cards;
a   c
a   b
a   a
b   d
b   b
b   a
c   c
c   d
c   a
d   g
e   f
;
run;

data want;
set have;
if _n_ = 1 then do;
  declare hash h();
  rc = h.definekey('a');
  rc = h.definedone();
end;
if h.add(KEY:a,DATA:a)=0 then if h.add(KEY:b,DATA:b)=0 then output;
drop rc;
run;
```

This is a greedy approach - in some cases there might be a valid output dataset with more rows that could be produced from your input dataset, but it should do a reasonable job most of the time.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Hash table is best way to solve this issue. Here is array:

```
data want;
    set have;
    array temp [50]$ _temporary_; ;
    array var A--B;
    retain temp j;
    if _n_=1 then do;
       output;
       j=1;
       do i=1 to dim(var);
          temp(j)=var(i);
          j+1;
       end;
    end;
    else do;
       do i=1 to dim(var);
          if whichc(var(i), of temp(*))>0 then return;
       end;
       output;
       do i=1 to dim(var);
          temp(j)=var(i);
          j+1;
       end;
    end;
    drop i j;
```

run;